# Cannot import modules from torch

Tags: python, pytorch, libraries, virtual-environment

I have installed torch 1.4.0. It has worked with all modules for 4 months well. But yesterday I ran into a problem in Jupyter Notebook such as:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
```

And it throws "cannot find module torch.optim". But it could import `torch` and `torch.nn`! I can't understand why. I didn't change venv or install other packages. Same problem with `torch.nn.Functional` and `torch.onnx`. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem solved with installing torch 1.6.0. I have no idea why this happened with torch 1.4.0. Anyway now it works.